# Restore PostgreSQL data into existing database

Tags: postgresql

Of course, the situation is such that I need a solution as soon as possible.

I have database in production in which I accidentally ran a script that deleted records that I did not want deleted.  Thankfully, I have a backup of the data before doing so as an `*.sql` file.  As such, I can manipulate it on my development environment to obtain only the data or even a dump file from `pg_dump`.

Whenever I try to use `pg_restore` or `psql` to import the file, it does not seem to import the missing rows.  It throws many errors, which I expect since it has duplicate data.  But I don't care about the duplicate data; I want the non-duplicated data back into the database.

Does anyone have any idea how to about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pg_dump with `--inserts`. This will get you a script with individual inserts for the rows instead of single `COPY` statements.

Run the script with `AUTOCOMMIT` on (the default).

Comment: Oh, thank you so very, very much!  You have saved the day!